# how to get type from `cxxNewExpr` in `clang-tidy`

Tags: clang++, clang-tidy

I'm trying to do a quick rewrite of our codebase to replace all instances of `new T(...)` with `New<T>(...)` (a custom function), so I can do some local measurements.

I think `clang-tidy` is the way to go here, so I've made a small clang tidy script, based off of [this tutorial I found](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTransformerTutorial.html). The script is able to run, but not pass tests, since I do not match things correctly.

However, I'm running into problems getting the type out of the matched new expression.

What I have so far is:

```
class ReplaceNewAndDeleteCheck : public utils::TransformerClangTidyCheck {      
 public:                                                                         
   ReplaceNewAndDeleteCheck(StringRef Name, ClangTidyContext *Context)           
      : TransformerClangTidyCheck(MakeRules(), Name, Context) {}                
};
```

Where `MakeRules` is defined as follows:

```
RewriteRuleWith<std::string> MakeRules() {
  std::string s = "new";
  return makeRule(
    cxxNewExpr().bind(s),
      changeTo(cat("New<", node(s), ">")), 
      cat("")
    );
  }
```

The script is able to run, but does not give the correct result. For example, with `int* x = new int(10);`, what I want is `int* x = New<int>(10);`, but what I get is `int* x = New<new int(10)>;`.

I know `MakeRules` is wrong, since I'm binding the entire new expression, not just the  on the entire  but I can't figure out how to either get the type and arguments out of the `new` expression, or to bind to those instead.